# SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, cucumber

We have UI automation test framework based on cucumber. Recently we have moved from Ruby 1.9.x to 2.2.0 and after that we are facing problem in login to our application via test framework. It says SSL connect reset problem.

Error Trace:

```
07:01:26 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:46:in `connect'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:46:in `ssl_connect'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:24:in `create_socket'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:739:in `block in connect'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `call'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:735:in `connect'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:497:in `query'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:170:in `query'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1238:in `do_get_block'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1021:in `block in do_request'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1129:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1016:in `do_request'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:858:in `request'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:761:in `post'
<-- our Code for login kick in to call httpclient --->
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:254:in `load_step_definitions'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:62:in `run!'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
07:01:26 D:/Ruby223/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.3.2/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: did you solve this? Having the same problem... I have a test suite using Ruby 1.9.3 and rest-client that is having this same problem. We are running against a C# webapp on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back after moving to ruby 2.0.0

Follow the following steps to solve it

1)Visit the url http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem  save the contents as a .pem file(Do not save it as a text file.Make sure the extension is .pem)

2)Copy the file to any path in your local eg: C:\ruby200\ca_cert.pem (in my case)

3)Now add an Environment variable with Variable SSL_CERT_FILE and value "C:\ruby200\ca_cert.pem"(without quotes)(path is in my case.Replace with appropriate path)
(Environment variables can be added by navigating to Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables)

4)Close all your command prompts and restart them.Things should work fine now

Answer (score -1):

I think your gem is updated.Add these lines in your code to solve the problem

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

before  `http.use_ssl = true`

I hope this might solve the problem.

Comment: Disabling ssl verification is a very bad idea. You shouldn't use that in production systems.

Comment: I'm ok with that for testing a webapp inhouse. Almost. I prefer verify peer with a cert.